# Delete an entire row if the content is found

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete an entire row if the cell starts with the text "Joe Smith" or "Jim Bob". This is the code I have from another question but need to modify:

```
Sub SimpleDeletingMechanism()

    Dim c As Range

    ' loop through all cells in range A1:A + last userd Row in column A
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        ' when Joe Smith is found in cell's content
        If InStr(1, c.Text, "Joe Smith", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            ' delete that row


        ' when Jim Bob is found in cell's content
        ElseIf InStr(1, c, "Jim Bob", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            ' delete that row

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me fill in the gap for deleting the row if one of the names is found please?

Comment: do you have a header row? if you do I'd use an autofilter rather than looping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you are deleting objects from a collection, you have to iterate backwards, otherwise, as the collection is re-indexed, you end up "skipping" some of the elements.

```
Sub SimpleDeletingMechanism()
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i as Long 

    Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For i = rng.Rows.Count to 1 Step -1 '// Iterate BACKWARDS over the collection
        Set c = rng.Cells(i,1)
        ' when Joe Smith is found in cell's content
        If InStr(1, c.Text, "Joe Smith", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            c.EntireRow.Delete


        ' when Jim Bob is found in cell's content
        ElseIf InStr(1, c, "Jim Bob", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

            c.EntireRow.Delete

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for explaining the backward iteration logic

Comment: +1 for pointing out the "skipping"